# How do i Create Static Page and Block in Magento?

Tags: magento-1.7

How do i create static page in magento? and also don't know about static block?

Comment: Have you tried to elaborate on your own before asking a question? There are quite a lot of resources out there explaining how static blocks and CMS pages are functioning in Magento.

Comment: @Tim sorry i got answer from maMarius.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can create static pages from the admin menu: CMS->Pages.
You can create static blocks from: CMS->Static Blocks.
For additional info refer to these links:
http://lmgtfy.com/?q=magento+static+blocks for static blocks and
[http://lmgtfy.com/?q=magento+static+pages](http://lmgtfy.com/?q=magento%20static%20pages) for pages

Comment: Thanks, What is different between Simple page and static page?

Comment: What do you mean by 'simple page'? Give me an example.

Comment: Sorry i don't know about any other type of page. bt i want to ask you that except static page, is there any other type of page available in magento?

Comment: There are pages that generated by a controller action. Go through this, maybe it will make thing clear: http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/magento-for-dev-part-1-introduction-to-magento

Comment: haha, never heard about this resource. good one!

Comment: @Tim. This is the best resource ever :).